# OSX utility for copy/pasting a text file in a FIFO queue fashion

Tags: copy-paste, text

There are a few similar questions regarding "clipboard managers" but nothing that quite suits my needs.

I often end up with an unformatted list of text that needs entering into various form fields. I'm looking for a utility that makes the clipboard act like a FIFO queue using a pre-defined text file of this nature.

Say I have a text file with 30 names

```
Adam
Alice
...
Will
Zara
```

I'd like to be able to paste this list into the clipboard manager. I'd then switch to the form, click the first box, press a hotkey and the first item would be "popped" from the list and pasted into the box. I'd then click the second box, press the hotkey again and the next name would be popped and pasted.

As a bonus, it would also be cool if I could do the reverse: click an item, press a hotkey and it's appended to a text file (or a list that can be easily exported as an unformatted text file). I've seen that lots of these other tools can build a list within the app itself, but I really need the output to be in a text file to use for other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found an app that meets my requirements.

[CleanClip](https://cleanclip.cc/) allows me to copy a list of strings (either one at a time or all together) into the clipboard and then iterate through them by pasting with CMD+V.

Each time an item is pasted, it moves to the next in the queue which means you can fill out forms VERY quickly.

It's perfect for testing HTML forms, where you need to paste a set of predefined data into multiple fields many, many times.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have seen to these requirements is [Flycut](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flycut-clipboard-manager/id442160987?mt=12) (free on the App Store)

It's extremely simple to use, though it won't automatically pop an item off the stack then move to the next one.

However, when you invoke Flycut (assuming you are starting at the top of the stack), you can just press the down arrow key <kbd>↓</kbd> to go to the next item.  When you release, it pastes what is in queue.

So, your sequence of keystrokes would be:

First:  <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>

Second: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>↓</kbd>

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Allan. It sounds promising although (at risk of sounding super anal) that's still one keystroke more than I'd like. I'll keep the question open in case anyone is able to suggest a click-paste-click-paste-click-paste style solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Copy'em Paste](http://apprywhere.com/copy-em-paste.html) is able to do that: in the global shortcut preference there are 2 actions:

- "Paste newer item in history"
- "Paste older item in history"

Comment: If chrome browser support is enough for you, the extension "Multi Copy Paste" might work as well. (https://www.producthunt.com/posts/multi-copy-paste)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same exact use case, but haven't found a good app.

I found an ok solution with Flycut:

1. Copy your strings in **reverse** order.
2. Paste twice: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>